# Undefined symbol: ___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ffmpeg

I'm getting this error when I try to run my project.

```
Undefined symbol: ___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow
```

Here, I'm included `pod 'mobile-ffmpeg-full', '4.3.2'` this frame work for video streaming.

**Complete error:**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow", referenced from:
      _read_key in mobileffmpeg(libmobileffmpeg_la-fftools_ffmpeg.o)
      _xmlNanoFTPCheckResponse in libxml2(nanoftp.o)
      _xmlNanoFTPCloseConnection in libxml2(nanoftp.o)
      _xmlNanoFTPList in libxml2(nanoftp.o)
      _xmlNanoFTPGet in libxml2(nanoftp.o)
      _OUTLINED_FUNCTION_8 in libxml2(nanoftp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

**Frame work Git link :** https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue @iOS?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue @iOS ?

Answer (score 6):

I had same Issue that solved by Following step.

1. comment all flipper function in podfile
2. remove/comment flipperInit in appDelegate
3. remove podfile.lock file in ios directory
4. pod install,
5. clean project
6. run again

Comment: No need to remove all those libraries (tho it will work). You can simply downgrade them, see [this answer](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30231#issuecomment-738674682)

Comment: None of these answers are correct. I'm not using PODs, just the compiler. Magically, fiddling with this setting made it go away https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337940/why-is-usr-include-missing-i-have-xcode-and-command-line-tools-installed-moja

Answer (score 2):

It's kinda a Pod issue, so there's no need to remove or commenting out the files. Simply downgrade the `Flipper-Folly` and `OpenSSL-Universal`. Search for the property on your `Podfile.lock`. Downgrade them one version step down. For example:

```
(2.2.1) to (2.2.0)
(= 1.0.2.20) to (= 1.0.2.19)
```

Comment: The issue seems OS/environment related, my colleague gets it on Mojave and this solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, great to know how helpful that was

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this several times. This issue occurs mostly on Mojave with Xcode version (11.3.1). Upgrading my macOS as well as Xcode solved it permanently.

Ways it can be resolved;

1. Upgrade your macOS to Catalina/Big Sur. And then your Xcode to version(12.4).
2. Downgrade Flipper-Folly(from 2.2.1 to 2.2.0) and OpenSSL-Universal(from 1.0.2.20 to 1.0.2.19) in Podfile.lock. Here is how it should look like

   - Flipper-Folly (2.2.0):
   - boost-for-react-native
   - CocoaLibEvent (~> 1.0)
   - Flipper-DoubleConversion
   - Flipper-Glog
   - OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.0.2.19)

- OpenSSL-Universal (1.0.2.19):

  - OpenSSL-Universal/Static (= 1.0.2.19)
  - OpenSSL-Universal/Static (1.0.2.19)

3. 

- Comment all flipper function in podfile
- Remove flipperInit in appDelegate
- Remove openSSl in podfile.lock
- Run pod install,
- Clean project
- Run again

It has also been answered here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30231

Answer (score 0):

```
I have solved by Following step.
 
remove podfile.lock file in ios directory
remove pods file in ios directory
pod install,
clean project
run again




comment all flipper function in podfile

# Enables Flipper.
      #
      # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
      # you should disable these next few lines.
     
        # use_flipper!
      # post_install do |installer|
        # flipper_post_install(installer)
      # end
```